# substring operation or regex in teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have data as below

```
col1
abc1234
abc 1234
12345
abc 1234 123456789
xyz1234567890a
```

I want output  having the string which is numeric with length >=5 characters, rest all records filtered.

I have tried function `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1, '[0-9]+')`, but it is not giving desired result

```
SELECT  col1 
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1, '[0-9]+') as num
FROM table1 
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL 
AND LENGTH(num) >5
```

expected output is as below

```
num
12345
123456789
1234567890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need tell the RegEx to return *at least five consecutive digits*, currently it's *at least one digit*. And of course, if you want `>= 5` you shouldn't write `> 5` :-)

```
RegExp_Substr(col1, '[0-9]{5,}')
```